# Spin up VM using Ansible without Vagrant

Tags: python, ansible, kvm, libvirt

I have a specific requirement where I can use only Ansible in my host machine without vagrant.

Two questions associated with it:

1. Is it possible to spin up a VM over the host machine with libvirt/KVM as hypervisor using ansible ? I know there is a module called virt in ansible which is capable of doing this. But I could'nt find any real example of how to use this. Appreciate if someone can point me to the example YAML through which I can spin up VM.
2. With Ansible, is it possible to run my playbook from python code ? If I am not wrong there is a python API supported by Ansible. But is it possible to give YAML file as input to this API which executes tasks from YAML.

Answer (score 2):

1. Of course - if you have SSH access to it.
2. Yes, you can run Ansible using its Python API or through command-line call. About passing YAML file - also - yes.